# htaccess redirect virtual directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ detail.php?name=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/directory/\.php$ detail2.php?name=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

The first RewriteRule should redirect anything (ending on php like domain.com/product1.php) from the root domain to detail.php (it can not affect things like domain.com/contact.php)

A 2nd RewriteRule should redirect anything from domain.com/directory/product-b1.php to detail2.php

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* /foldernamehere/index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

paste this code in your .htaccess file it will resolve your problem